# CALayer NAN deleting section of UITableView with custom UItableviewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sections

Hi i dont know where to look further im totally stuck:

Scenario: When i leave edit mode of my view i delete rows and sections of my table.
The table consits of different custom cells which have animation when entering or leaving
editmode.

Problem: Sometimes and i dont know when, i cant reproduce it, the app crashes with a "
CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [nan 2.03571e-10]" error message.

I looked for hours now but i cant find the error therefor i provide some more code maybe anyone knows where it happens:

I call tis method to leave edit mode of the table in it setupDetailEditMode gets called.

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {


if(editing)
{..}
else{

        tableShowEditMode = NO;
    [self setupDetailEditMode];

    [self createPersonTableHeader];
    [self clearAllEmptyFieldsFromArray];
        [self saveUserProfile];

        [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
        [profileTable setEditing:editing animated:YES];
......}
```

**This code is where i delete sections.... some of the sections still have rows which is no problem cause they will be deleted by deleting the section in the following function it crashes last line:**

```
part of function **setupDetailEditMode**:
   //Phone Section
    if(removedRowsPhone)

    {
        if(app.isitUserProfile.isitPhone.count == 0)
            [sectionOperationIndexSet addIndex:sectionWorked];

        sectionWorked++;
    }

    //Email Section 
    if(removedRowsEmail)
    {
        if(app.isitUserProfile.isitEmail.count == 0)
            [sectionOperationIndexSet addIndex:sectionWorked];

        sectionWorked++;
    }



    //update table data structur
    [self buildCurrentTableStructure];

    //delete sections <<<<<**here will crash the app sometimes**
    [profileTable deleteSections:sectionOperationIndexSet withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

**I add a random custom cell i use maybe there is something wrong that causes the crash in layoutsubviews:**

```
- (void) layoutSubviews {


    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (self.editing)
    {
        primaryField.enabled = YES;

        // (self.editing && !self.showingDeleteConfirmation)
        star1Img.frame = CGRectMake(87.0,30.0,20.0, 20.0);
        star2Img.frame = CGRectMake(111.0,30.0,20.0, 20.0);
        star3Img.frame = CGRectMake(135.0,30.0,20.0, 20.0);
        star4Img.frame = CGRectMake(159.0,30.0,20.0, 20.0);
        star5Img.frame = CGRectMake(183.0,30.0,20.0, 20.0);

        //primaryLabel.frame = CGRectMake(primaryLabel.frame.origin.x, 8.0,180.0 , 17.0);
        primaryField.frame = CGRectMake(primaryField.frame.origin.x, 8.0,180.0 , 17.0);
        secondaryLabel.frame = CGRectMake(secondaryLabel.frame.origin.x,18.0, 65.0 , 21.0);

    }
    else
    {
        primaryField.enabled = NO;

        star1Img.frame = CGRectMake(29.0,27.0,10.0, 10.0);
        star2Img.frame = CGRectMake(39.0,27.0,10.0, 10.0);
        star3Img.frame = CGRectMake(49.0,27.0,10.0, 10.0);
        star4Img.frame = CGRectMake(59.0,27.0,10.0, 10.0);
        star5Img.frame = CGRectMake(69.0,27.0,10.0, 10.0);

        primaryField.frame = CGRectMake(primaryField.frame.origin.x, 14.0,213.0 , 17.0);
        secondaryLabel.frame = CGRectMake(14.0,6.0, 65.0 , 21.0);
    }

} // layoutSubviews*/


- (void) setStarRating:(int) rating
{

    if(rating>=1)
        [star1Img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"goldstar20.png"]];
......}
```

I am very frustrated atm because i cant find this bug it would be very niice if anyone has a hint or find the bug. Anything will help. Thanks

-Bevo

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked through your code very much, but I had something similar once. There was a view that got released but did want to be painted again - basically a retain thing. Hard to find - or understand - even via profiler. You should check with the profiler if there is a leak anywhere.